# How to update phantomjs 1.9.8 to phantomjs 2.1.1 on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, phantomjs, updates, reinstall

I cant reinstall phantomjs 1.9.8 to 2.1.1 version on my ubuntu 16.04
Please help. 
1.9.8 give me an errors when I write a spin functions, in documentation see that this ploblem I can solve with reinstalation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I just installed phantomjs 2.1.1 in ubuntu 16.04 with the following steps, which I found after a bit of googling :

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm -g install phantomjs-prebuilt
```

Comment: Since PhantomJS has nothing to do with node.js or npm (installed only for convenience), this installs a whole ecosystem for a single binary that has nothing to do with the ecosystem.

Comment: True enough. The nodejs (and nodejs-legacy) are required by npm to successfully install phantomjs. The steps I followed were for use with selenium in python. The npm could always be uninstalled once done. This was just a very quick way to get the PhantomJS driver working with selenium.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I would do it if I were developing. The packages are versioned to nodejs and not ubuntu:

Use `nvm`: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

```
touch ~/.profile
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.7/install.sh | bash

source ~/.profile
# node 6x
nvm install 6.5.0 
npm install phantomjs@2.1.1

# node 4x
nvm install 4.5.0
nvm use 4.5.0
npm install phantomjs@1.9.19

# node 0.12x
nvm install 0.12
npm show phantomjs@* version
npm install phantomjs@1.9.8
```

Perhaps we are developing on `0.10, 0.12, 4.X, iojs4.x, 6.X, etc` well now we have access to choose whichever version of phantomjs:

```
jmunsch@ubuntu:~$ npm show phantomjs@* version
phantomjs@0.0.1 '0.0.1'
phantomjs@0.0.2 '0.0.2'
phantomjs@0.0.3 '0.0.3'
phantomjs@0.0.4 '0.0.4'
phantomjs@0.0.5 '0.0.5'
phantomjs@0.0.6 '0.0.6'
phantomjs@0.0.7 '0.0.7'
phantomjs@0.0.8 '0.0.8'
phantomjs@0.0.9 '0.0.9'
phantomjs@0.1.0 '0.1.0'
phantomjs@0.1.1 '0.1.1'
phantomjs@0.2.0 '0.2.0'
phantomjs@0.2.1 '0.2.1'
phantomjs@0.2.2 '0.2.2'
phantomjs@0.2.3 '0.2.3'
phantomjs@0.2.4 '0.2.4'
phantomjs@0.2.5 '0.2.5'
phantomjs@0.2.6 '0.2.6'
phantomjs@1.9.8 '1.9.8'
phantomjs@1.9.9 '1.9.9'
phantomjs@1.9.10 '1.9.10'
phantomjs@1.9.11 '1.9.11'
phantomjs@1.9.12 '1.9.12'
phantomjs@1.9.13 '1.9.13'
phantomjs@1.9.15 '1.9.15'
phantomjs@1.9.16 '1.9.16'
phantomjs@1.9.17 '1.9.17'
phantomjs@1.9.18 '1.9.18'
phantomjs@1.9.19 '1.9.19'
phantomjs@2.1.1 '2.1.1'
phantomjs@2.1.2 '2.1.2'
phantomjs@2.1.3 '2.1.3'
phantomjs@1.9.20 '1.9.20'
phantomjs@2.1.7 '2.1.7'
```

## system-wide for deployment scenarios, etc.

Here is how using the tarball

```
export PHANTOM_JS_VERSION=2.1.1
wget "https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-$PHANTOM_JS_VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2"
tar xvfj "./phantomjs-$PHANTOM_JS_VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2"
ln -sf "./phantomjs-$PHANTOM_JS_VERSION-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs" "/usr/bin"
```

Tested on ubuntu 14.04, perhaps moving the folder to another place other than `./`

## update for 16.04:

wget may or may not work see: https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/161

```
# install dependencies
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig
# extract the tar file
tar xvfj "./phantomjs-$PHANTOM_JS_VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2"
# use full path
ln -sf "$(pwd)/phantomjs-$PHANTOM_JS_VERSION-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs" "/usr/bin"
```

## Error

> phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Try:

```
 sudo apt-get install libfontconfig
```

Comment: @3zzy your're right, updated looked like a dependency issue, and linking to a relative path might have been an issue. Also for whatever reason `wget` wasn't working so I `scp` the tar ball over to the machine. Added github issue with the same 403 acess denied error.

Answer (score 5):

So, jmunsch's answer works for me, but just to provide a clear and minimal recipe:

```
export PHANTOM_JS_VERSION=2.1.1

sudo apt-get install libfontconfig

wget "https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-$PHANTOM_JS_VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2"

tar xvfj "./phantomjs-$PHANTOM_JS_VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2"

ln -sf "$(pwd)/phantomjs-$PHANTOM_JS_VERSION-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs" "/usr/bin"
```

The last line requires sudo because of /usr/bin, but you can put the symlink anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

For those who have problems to install like me

**it is more easy than you think...**

- I uninstall phantomjs: Remove phantomjs from ubuntu `sudo apt-get remove phantomjs` or remove npm folder of `/node_modules/phantomjs` it will be in `/`, maybe you will need to remove `ln` the link of phantomjs in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin/` the name of it is `phantomjs`

Example

```
//use this if you installed with apt-get
sudo apt-get remove phantomjs    *remove the phantomjs
rm /usr/bin/phantomjs            *use this if the link didn't remove.

//use this if you installed from npm: like this: npm install phantomjs
rm -R /node_modules/phantomjs    *note: it will be in other folder, search it.
```

- install phantomjs from npm: `npm install phantomjs` from `/` directory, npm install it in folder `/node_module/phantomjs`

Example

```
cd /;
npm install phantomjs
```

- Test bin file

Example

```
//check version of phantomjs
/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs -v
/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs test.js
```

- link file bin to `/usr/bin`:

Example

`ln -sf /node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs`

- check version of it to see if it's ok
   `phantomjs -v` in my case `2.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

phantomjs 2.1.1 is now currently bundled with 16.04 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/phantomjs), so you should be able to install/upgrade it as a system package.

Update: This answer exists for informative purposes, but it is **not recommended** to use the system package version now due to issues such as: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phantomjs/+bug/1605628 This is related to an issue with file upload that was fixed upstream, but the nature of the fix prevented it from working as a system package.

The best current option is use the prebuilt binary from: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/download

Answer (score 0):

As approved steps did not work for me, I am sharing the solution I found.

```
# Install phantomJS
export PHANTOM_JS="phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64"
wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
sudo tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2

sudo mv $PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/share
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin

# Sanity check 
phantomjs --version
>>> 2.1.1
```